# react js console.log is not writing to my terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console.log

I don't know if I did something wrong.

After I run my app, this is what terminal shows:

[Here is a screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkRVi.png)

And whatever I tried to log to terminal using "console.log" doesn't show up there

I don't know where console.log has its output directed to but obviously not my terminal...

Comment: What file are you logging from? If the code is on the client side, it'll log in the browser

Comment: CTRL+F12 Console Tab

Comment: try going to `localhost:3000` in your browser

Answer (score 27, accepted):

React.js applications run in your browser, not server. If you're using Chrome, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to launch the browser console to see the logs.

The logs will only show in your terminal if you use `console.log` in your Node.js server-side code.