# Copying/redirecting browser console output to shell

Tags: reactjs, console.log

Is there a way, in Linux, to make the `electron` executable copy or redirect output sent to its console to the *shell* console, i.e. when I run it from a terminal?

For instance, if I run, in a shell, `electron foo.js`, where `foo.js` contains simply `console.log("foo")`, I get the `foo` message echoed back to my terminal.

However, when I run a React app, the output of `console.log` is directed to the browser's console ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867977/react-js-console-log-is-not-writing-to-my-terminal)).

Is there a way to copy/redirect the outputs sent to the browser Console, so that they will *also* be sent to the shell console? This can be very useful for some kinds of debugging (e.g. using `grep` and regexes).

Alternatively, if there are other methods than `console.log` that allow writing to the shell which created the browser process, that would also be helpful.

**Edit**: @0stone0 mentioned the difference between server code and client code; from the point of view of debugging, since I am running a local process, the browser could very well decide to copy its console output to `stdout`/`stderr`. I fail to see why technically Chromium could not do it; requiring an API or websockets for this use case seems excessive, but if that is indeed necessary (e.g. for security reasons), that is a valid answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file):

> Q: Does anyone know of a way to save the console.log output in Chrome to a file? Or how to copy the text out of the console?
>
> A: Enable logging from the command line using the flags:
>
> ```
> --enable-logging --v=1
> ```

I then combined it with the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447497/how-do-i-set-a-chromium-command-line-flag-in-electron) to set the Chromium flag in my Electron app:

```js
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-logging');
```

And that is enough for me to get messages in my console, such as:

```
[1234:0328/3923.5981:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "logging", source: file:///home/user/app/main.js
```